# Call JSNI Java function from javascript via a frame in GWT - $wnd is undefined error

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, jsni

I know I'm probably just doing something stupid but I cannot find an example that actually shows how to call a Java method from javascript using GWT.

[I've followed the documentation almost verbatim where is says:](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html#calling)

```
package mypackage;

public class Account {
private int balance = 0;
public int add(int amt) {
  balance += amt;
}

public native void exportAdd() /*-{
    var that = this;
    $wnd.add = $entry(function(amt) {
      that.@mypackage.Account::add(I)(amt);
    });
}-*/;
}
```

Then you can call it in JS using

```
$wnd.add(5);
```

But that results in an error for me that says "$wnd is undefined".

This is my code:
I export the function call

```
public native void exportPaymentProcessComplete()/*-{
    var that = this;
    console.log('exportingPaymentProcessComplete');
    $wnd.paymentProcessComplete = $entry(function(result){
        that.@com.ec.client.checkout.Presenter::paymentProcessComplete(Ljava/lang/String;)(result);
    });

}-*/;
```

I have a simple function that's being called (with a breakpoint because I've yet to get it to be called)

```
public void paymentProcessComplete(String result){
    if(result != null){

    }
}
```

This is the tricky part and probably where I'm going wrong. The JSNI call is being made from an iframe when it loads. I think it has to do with trying to call the parent window's javascript functions but I'm not sure how to refer to the parents $wnd object.

I've tried this:

```
response.getWriter().print("<script type=\"text/javascript\">parent.$wnd.paymentProcessComplete(\"SUCCESS\");</script>");
```

Which is when I get the "$wnd is undefined" error.

And also this:

```
response.getWriter().print("<script type=\"text/javascript\">parent.paymentProcessComplete(\"SUCCESS\");</script>");
```

Which gives me a "Unable to get property 'paymentProcessComplete' of undefined or null reference". Which is basically the same error as "$wnd is undefined".

Anyone have any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some deeper digging, I discovered that the JSNI code that was exporting/exposing my JAVA method was throwing a Cast exception because it was trying to attach it to the Presenter class it was a part of instead of the Window.

So this code:

```
public native void exportPaymentProcessComplete()/*-{
    var that = this;
    console.log('exportingPaymentProcessComplete');
    $wnd.paymentProcessComplete = $entry(function(result){
        that.@com.ec.client.checkout.Presenter::paymentProcessComplete(Ljava/lang/String;)(result);
    });
}-*/;
```

Became this code:

```
public native void exportPaymentProcessComplete()/*-{
    $wnd.paymentProcessComplete = $entry(function(result){
        @com.ra.ec.client.checkout.CheckoutPresenter::paymentProcessComplete(Ljava/lang/String;)(result);
    });     
}-*/;
```

Which also meant the paymentProcessComplete() method had to have a static modifier applied to it's declaration.

```
private static void paymentProcessComplete(String result){
```

Answer (score 1):

when compiling your GWT App `$wnd` is replaced by `window`.
So when you are trying to call a exported method from inside an iframe call it like this:
`window.parent.paymentProcessComplete("SUCCESS")`

Comment: That did appear to change things. I'm getting a slightly different error "Object doesn't support property or method 'paymentProcessComplete'". It sounds like I'm referencing "$wnd" correctly now, at least. Thank you. :)